# minimal representation of convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis

Here is a question about the convex hull.

Let $S$ be a set and $\bar{S}$ be the closed convex hull of $S$, i.e., $\bar{S}$ is the smallest convex set that contains $S$. Then is the following claim true?

"$\forall~s\in\bar{S}$, $s$ can be written as a convex combination of a finite set of vectors in $S$"

I feel that it should be correct intuitively. But I am not sure. Is there any reference or counter example? I remember for convex hull (not closed convex hull), there is a minimal representation theorem to support this claim. But I don't know if it is also true for "closed" convex hull. I cannot perceive this difference

Comment: You say "closed convex hull", and then you say i.e. and give the definition of the _convex hull_. Which do you mean to ask about? The answer is yes for the convex hull but no for the closed convex hull...

Comment: Is $S$ a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ or are you allowing more general sets?  If $S$ is open, then the statement you write is false, consider the open unit disk as $S$, then $\overline{S}$ is the closed disk and the points on the boundary are not convex combinations.  If $S$ is a point set, then the vertices of $\overline{S}$ are in $S$.  We can then triangulate (or tetrahedralize or ...) $\overline{S}$ and write any element as a convex combination of the vertices of the simplex that contains it.

Comment: See [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_(convex_hull)?wprov=sfsi1).

Comment: And if $S$ is compact, so is the convex hull of $S$.